# Need a solution for USB splitter and soundcard

Tags: usb, audio, sound-card, splitter, music-management

What I am trying to achieve is to use my sound card changeably, once with a computer, once with a phone. The USB sound card (I think for that case it doesn't matter which one, because the sound is converted automatically into analog) has got a male USB input.

My first idea was to connect all together with an USB Y splitter (2 male -> 1 female), but i think that is not possible, since one of the male can be always only power.

What kind of splitter should I use and will it even work? I guess now that probably the super correctness policy of our time will not allow us to define the model by name, but you could at least describe how this splitter would look like, what specifications it should have.

Comment: Every USB device can only be connected to one master/host at the same time. If you want to connect it to two hosts you need a switch like a KVM switch where you can manually select to which host the device is cnnected at the moment.

Comment: USB connectors need to be specified/described by more than just the gender (e.g. male ore female).  There's the type (e.g. A, B, or C) and the size (e.g. full/standard, mini, and micro).

Comment: @Robert Thanks, I think I know what to do. I would have to buy a kvm switch with at least two male connectors

Comment: @sawdust what difference does it have if it was USB A/B/C?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Connectors

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for he link, but what meaning does it have for that case, specifically?